# Cannot go to new line in text wrap

Tags: c++

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and can't figure it out on my own.

```
void text_printer(char text[], int wrap_size)
{
    bool space_check;
    for (int sub = 0; text[sub] != '\0'; sub++)
    {
        space_check = false;

        if (sub % wrap_size == 0 && sub != 0)
            space_check = true;

        if (space_check == true && text[sub] == ' ')
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << text[sub];
        }
    }
}
```

The second if statement doesn't execute when it's supposed to.

```
ah yes you are here for tea
```

If I pass this to it, it won't change when it's outputted.

It compiles just fine and there are no errors so I assume it's a problem with my code, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: It's unclear what you have saying..

Comment: Sorry, I had trouble describing it. Hopefully that cleared it up a little.

Comment: What is the value of `wrap_size`?

Comment: wrap_size is 9 for the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of troubles in your code. I will describe one of it. Another has been described by @artm. What if `wrap_size` is 9 an the input line is like "12345678901234567 12 45 78 01". Then your code is going to split it like

```
12345678901234567
12
45 78 01
```

I suppose it is not what you want and must be

```
12345678901234567
12 45 78
01
```

So the proper solution should be like bellow

```
void text_printer(char text[], int wrap_size)
{
    for (int sub = 0, count = 0; text[sub] != '\0'; sub++, count++)
    {
        bool space_check = count >= wrap_size; 
        if (space_check && text[sub] == ' ')
        {
            cout << endl;
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << text[sub];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you have a flaw in this logic `if (space_check == true && text[sub] == ' ')` What happens when `space_check == true` but `text[sub]` isn't a space, now `space_check` will be reset to `false` on the next loop, and you will miss the new line.

This is one way to get your logic right. Add a new variable `idx` to keep track of how many characters have passed the last space character, then make sure to break the line (and reset `idx` for the next round).

```
int idx = 0;
for (int sub = 0; text[sub] != '\0'; sub++, idx++)
{
    space_check = false;

    if (idx >= wrap_size && sub != 0)
        space_check = true;

    if (space_check == true && text[sub] == ' ')
    {
        cout << endl;
        idx = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << text[sub];
    }
}
```